# Must we ditch From Trait to make code navigable

Tags: rust, traits

We found the rust `From` trait is lacking IDE (both PyCharm and vscode) support:

```
impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(order: A) -> Self {...}  // Impl
}

// order is of Type A
let order: B = order.into();  // Usage
```

Neither IDE is able to navigate from usage to implementation or vice versa.
If we use

`let order = B::from(order);`

then navigating from usage to impl is a breeze, but from impl to usage takes vscode 10 seconds on our code base.

If we ditch the `From` trait altogether, i.e.

```
impl B {
    pub(crate) fn from(order: A) -> Self {...}
}
```

then navigating either direction is instantaneous. Our Rust-consultants hate this, but we Rust beginners will understand and maintain the code base so much more efficiently!

Is there a best practice to get IDEs properly navigating (ctrl+left-click and "Go to reference") between `From` usage and implementation.

Comment: We cannot design language around limitations of Intellisense so answer is obviously no.

Comment: The `we` in the title means our small team working on a small project. Not out to change the world...

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. It seems you've already found a solution, are you asking whether it's idiomatic?

Comment: I do want that the IDE supports me when using the `From` trait. I was asking if anybody knows how to get the IDE to do that. Or knows about an extension. Or knows about a setting etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Go to X" behavior works both ways as I'd expect in VSCode with rust-analyzer, but I can see how it can be unsatisfying due to how `From`/`Into` is designed.

The `.into()` method is *not* provided by the `From` trait, it is provided by the `Into` trait. The reason that implementing `From` seems to allow `.into()` to work is due to `Into`'s [generic implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#impl-Into%3CU%3E-for-T) that implements `Into<U> for T where U: From<T>`. And because of that behavior, almost nothing implements `Into` directly and would implement `From` instead.

What this means in your IDE though is that navigating to `.into()` will almost always lead you to the generic implementation, which isn't very helpful but its also what I'd expect. There is some discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/13394) that would propose navigating to the relevant `From` implementation instead, though nothing has come of it yet and would have to be handled as a special case.

But navigating via `::from(_)` appears to work just fine: "Go to implementation" on `String::from("")` for example leads to the `From<&str> for String` implementation, and navigating from `fn from(...` there shows me all uses of that particular implementation. It takes a moment but I've only tested on a medium-ish code base so if the performance is a problem for you then you can file an issue.

That all being said, you don't *need* to use `From` if you don't want to. A `From` implementation would be required if you relied on utilizing the conversion in a generic context and thus I would encourage you to provide it anyway if at all appropriate. But that doesn't mean you have to use it directly in your own code: if `from_a()` or `into_b()` improves clarity then by all means add that as an option as well. Even the standard library does it (see `String::into_bytes` vs `From<String> for Vec<u8>` for example). I wouldn't recommend an inherent `from` or `into` method since that would be easily confused with the trait method; give it a better name.

And as a final note, you shouldn't put all your eggs in one basket. Especially as a beginner. Your IDE is only one source of discoverability: the generated documentation and any supplemental examples, tests, and mdbooks work together to form a complete understanding.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! Btw we sometimes need to convert an `A` to a `B` with a context. For example we could then `B::from_with_address(order, address)`